# API Management - Response Time

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-api-management

We are working on setting up an API Management portal for one of our Web API. We are using eventhubs for logging the events and we are transferring the event messages to Azure Blob storage using Azure functions.

We would like to know how can we find the Time taken by API Management portal for providing the response for a message (we are capturing the time taken at the back end api layer but not from the API Management layer).

Regards,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the correct way of doing this, but still get an idea of how much time each request is taking. We can actually use the context variable to set the start time in the inbound policy node and then calculate the end time in the outbound node.

Answer (score 2):

The simpler solution is to enable [Azure Monitor Diagnostic Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-of-diagnostic-logs) for the Apimanagement service. You will get raw logs for each request including

**durationMs** - interval between receiving request line and headers from a client and writing last chunk of response body to a client. All writes and reads include network latency.

**BackendTime** - time spent waiting on backend response

**ClientTime** - time spent with client for request and response

**CacheTime** - time spent on fetching from cache

You can also refer this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/AzureApiMgmt/Monitor-API-Management-with-Azure-Monitor).